# Obtaining Random Numbers from irregular Ranges

Tags: javascript, random

I want to get a random number from (0,2,6,8,4) or such ranges. Currently I loop till I get appropriate Num.

```
boxNum = getRandomNum(0, 8);

  while (boxNum == 1 || boxNum == 3 || boxNum == 5 || boxNum == 7))
    boxNum = getRandomNum(0, 8);
```

Is there any other way to do this?? The while loop crashes the page after some turns.

Comment: Why not make a random choice from an array of the valid numbers? Your method might *never* succeed.

Comment: What is your implementation of `getRandomNum`? I recommend the 4th algorithm from the MDN page on [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: function getRandomNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty Simple You store the desired value in the array . Get the value from it randomly .

```
    var RangeOfnumber = [0,2,4,6,8];
function getRandomNumber(){
var randomNumGen= RangeOfnumber[Math.floor(Math.random()*RangeOfnumber.length)];
 return randomNumGen;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... 2 * getRandomNum(0,4) ?